# Change the ToC number to text input

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently writing my thesis with LaTex and my professor told me that the appendix should not be completely referenced in the ToC.
There should be something like

Appendix..............................112

A important figures .................113

B tables .........................available on provided flash drive

Is there a way to get the text in the table of contents instead of the number?

Comment: I think this could be done with  `\titletoc`, which comes with `titlesec`.

Comment: Can you please add a short example (to the question) that  shoes the document class and your settings (packages etc.) regarding the ToC and the appendix?

Comment: To what level (counter tocdepth) does you TOC use?  You could implement the individual appendices as lower level divisions.  I believe the appendix package can only select between chapters and sections, but it shouldn't be too difficult to implement a custom \appendixes.

Answer (score 2):

The following provides a template that you can use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Regular chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\chapter*{Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendices}

\appendix

\chapter{Important figures}
\lipsum[1-50]

%\clearpage% Not really necessary; depends on your use-case
\refstepcounter{chapter}% Advance chapter counter, if not using \chapter explicitly
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \protect\contentsline{chapter}% Format like a regular \chapter
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}Important tables}% Chapter number and title
  {Flash drive}% Chapter page
}

\chapter{Other important things}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

You would insert a `\chapter`-like entry into the ToC with a "page number" of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{6em} % more space for ToC page numbers or text
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
Some text.
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{section}{Tables}{on flash drive}}
\textbf{Tables} % on flash drive
\chapter{Two}
More text
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

The above uses the general LaTeX methods so no need for any packages. The macro `\addtocontents` puts its argument into the `.toc` file and the macro `\contentsline` is used to produce a ToC entry. A full explanation is given in Chapter 9 *Contents lists* of the `memoir` class manual (`> texdoc memoir`). The class also provides several methods for controlling the appearance of the ToC (and LoF and LoT).